# Is Glass self-explanatory?

Tags: suggested-order, split, unbreakable, glass

I know *Glass* is the third part of a trilogy. Since I am planning to watch it, I want to know if it is self-explanatory enough to skip previous films. Do I need to watch both *Unbreakable* and *Split* before *Glass*?

<sub>Note: I have seen *Unbreakable* but not *Split*.</sub>

Comment: The weird thing about Split - if you don't already know before you see it, you'd never know it belonged to the trilogy. I Split saw it 15 years after Unbreakable & never made the connection until the recent blurb about Glass. [I did watch them both again last week just to see.] I haven't seen Glass yet, so I can't really make this into an answer.

Comment: Oops, apologies for the rather random typing above - it should say "I saw Split 15 years after Unbreakable".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should watch Split and Unbreakable before watching Glass in order to understand the significance of several of the relationships between some of the main characters. There is some explanation within the film as to who they are, so for factual purposes you do not necessarily need to have seen Split before Glass, but I think there is a high potential to miss some of this explanation and/or to misunderstand the importance of it unless you've seen the previous films. It was not presented as a stand alone film, rather it is very much a sequel of Unbreakable and Split.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the story explores both the previous movies.
You will understand the plot as the movie is self-explanatory itself,
but I would suggest it will be more interesting if you watch split.
But if you have seen Unbreakable then you will surely understand the movie.
Hope this helps...:)

Answer (score 1):

I saw Glass at the weekend, never saw the other movies, and honestly, I found it easy to understand the plot and I found it enjoyable to watch.